# jQuery - Unable to append a row in a table

Tags: jquery

My HTML is like this -

```
<table id="#test_table">
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

My script.js is like this -

```
$(function() {
    $("#test_table").append('<tr><td>column 1 value</td><td>column 2 value</td></tr>');
});
```

But still I see only two rows and unable to see third row which I append from jQuery. Also tried befor and after. I'm using Chrome and also nothing is there when I inspect element. Please help

Comment: When you give an element an ID, don't include the hash

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. Should be `<table id="test_table">`

Comment: Oh God. Silly me. What am I doing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. The `id` attribute should just contain the `id`. The `#` is a CSS thing meaning "I'm an `id` selector" and is *followed* by the `id`; the `#` isn't *part* of the `id`.
2. `tables` always have a `tbody`, even if you don't write one in your HTML. For that reason, I always write them, and then append the row to the `tbody`, not the `table`.

That said, re #2: At least in the current version of Chrome, Chrome just handles that for you, so it may not be an issue with modern browsers:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#test_table").append('<tr><td>column 1 value</td><td>column 2 value</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test_table">
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Still, I prefer the clarity and not relying on the kindness of browser writers:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#test_table tbody").append('<tr><td>column 1 value</td><td>column 2 value</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test_table">
<tbody>
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: FWIW, #2 isn't an issue with current Firefox or IE either, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hash from the ID in HTML.

```
<table id="test_table">
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
</table>

$(function() {
    $("#test_table").append('<tr><td>column 1 value</td><td>column 2 value</td></tr>');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24uf3tm8/)

Comment: This has already been pointed out in the comments. You should vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo instead of farming rep from it.

Comment: T.J. Crowder has replied to the question.  Why don't you tell him this?

Comment: Because he added a point about how to append a row, and while I don't think it's worth an upvote, it's more than just a note about the `#` typo.

Comment: Alright, respecting your 90k+ rep.  I am not farming for rep, this is my one of the new year resolutions to contribute to StackOverflow in whatsoever manner possible.